# Not gate with 3 LEDS attached after NPN transistor

Tags: circuit-design, logic-gates

I want to build a circuit that turns 3 LEDS (L1,L2,L3) on if the button isn't pressed and turns a different set of 3 LEDS (L4,L5,L6) on when the button is pressed.  Only 1 of the sets of LEDS should be able to be lit up at a time though so pressing or releasing the button will turn off the currently lit up set.  I built and assembled this schematic:
[image]

When I don't press the button L1,L2,L3 light up properly.  When I press the button L4,L5,L6 light up, but L1,L2,L3 don't turn off.  How can I go about getting L1,L2,L3 to turn off when the button is pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way is to use a 1PDT push button..

Otherwise you probably need another transistor \$Q2\$ that is normally biased on and is turned off when the original one \$Q1\$ turns on.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkAXti.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You CAN tie \$Q1\$ to \$R2\$ via a diode \$D7\$, but then \$R2\$ needs to be 1/2W and \$Q1\$ needs to dump a lot more current than you need.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVkK1Z.png)</sup>

Comment: That Power waster version will have all LEDs turned on at the same time  when the button is not pressed.

Comment: @lappie oops..good point... That's what I get for rushing.. Fixed.

Comment: Wow, big detailed schematics, good stuff...you can tell you've recently started working from home again, Trevor :-) :-)

Comment: @TonyM.. OH YES... Working!... I knew I was supposed to be doing something else... LOL ;-)

Comment: You're contributing good stuff to society's up and coming new generation, you can't get a more valuable use of time than this :-)  (don't try telling the client that when they check in on things)

Comment: Wow this is such an awesome response!  I have 2 questions: First, can you explain why my circuit didn't work properly?  Second,  Why does the circuit with a diode waste power?  Like it has 1 less resistor (or 2kvohms) less resistance so shouldn't it use up less power?

Comment: @user2417339 in the wasteful circuit you are using the transistor to divert the current from the right LED chain. That means R2 has almost 9V across it. That's 4mA being sucked out your battery and ~0.405W of heat being dissipated to turn something off.

Comment: Will circuit 2 work if I replace r3 & r4 with 1k ohm resistors

Comment: @user2417339 yes

Comment: How can I calculate what range r3 and r4 need to be in for the circuit to work?

Comment: @user2417339 You want the transistor to be saturated on, so you need a value low enough to achieve that while you drive the leds at whatever current you want to drive them at.